# Why does triangle expands when i rotate it?

Tags: c, graphics, ascii-art

I've been trying to make a collision simulation in c with `ncurses` but there is one major problem.
It seems that my triangle expands with rotational motion and I don't know what's causing it.
It also doesn't expand when I comment out the `updateTri()` function but then it also doesn't rotate.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<curses.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<unistd.h>
    
struct winsize win;
    
typedef struct vector2d{
    double x;
    double y;
} Vec2;
    
typedef struct triangle{
    Vec2 *p1;
    Vec2 *p2;
    Vec2 *p3;
}Tri;
    
//
//DRAWING STUFF
//
    
void swapp(Vec2 *p1,Vec2 *p2){Vec2 tmp = *p1;*p1 = *p2;*p2 = tmp;}
    
double inpolx(Vec2 p1,Vec2 p2,double y){ //interpolate x from p1 to p2 with y variable
    double x = p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x)*(y - p1.y)/(p2.y - p1.y);
    return x;
}
    
void DSline(double x1,double x2,double y ){ //Draws Simple line
        
    double x,x2l;
    if(x1<x2){
        x=x1;x2l = x2;
    }else{
        x=x2;x2l = x1;
    }
    do{mvprintw(y/2,x,"#");
    } while(x++<x2l);
}
    
void drawtup(Tri t){
    Vec2 *p1 = t.p1,*p2 = t.p2,*p3 = t.p3;
    double invslope1 = (p2->x - p1->x) / (p2->y - p1->y),invslope2 = (p3->x - p1->x) / (p3->y - p1->y),curx1 = p1->x,curx2 = p1->x;
    for(double Y = p1->y; Y < p2->y; Y++){
        DSline(curx1,curx2,Y);
        curx1 += invslope1;
        curx2 += invslope2;
    }
}

void drawtdown(Tri t){
    Vec2 *p1 = t.p1,*p2 = t.p2,*p3 = t.p3;
    double invslope1 = (p3->x - p1->x) / (p3->y - p1->y),invslope2 = (p3->x - p2->x) / (p3->y - p2->y),curx1 = p3->x,curx2 = p3->x;
    for(double Y = p3->y; Y > p1->y; Y--){
        DSline(curx1,curx2,Y);
        curx1 -= invslope1;
        curx2 -= invslope2;
    }
}
    
void scanln(Tri tr){
    if(tr.p2->y < tr.p1->y){ swapp(tr.p2, tr.p1); }if(tr.p3->y <tr.p1->y){ swapp(tr.p3, tr.p1); }if(tr.p3->y < tr.p2->y){ swapp(tr.p3, tr.p2); }
    
    if(tr.p3->y == tr.p2->y){
        drawtup(tr);
    }
    else if(tr.p1->y == tr.p2->y){
        drawtdown(tr);
    }
    else{
        Vec2 p4 = {inpolx(*tr.p1,*tr.p3,tr.p2->y),tr.p2->y};
        Tri tu = {tr.p1,tr.p2,&p4};
        Tri td = {tr.p2,&p4,tr.p3};
        drawtup(tu);
        drawtdown(td);
    }
}
    
//
//SIMULATION CALCULATIONS
//
    
Vec2 crossd(Vec2 p ,double d){
    Vec2 r = {-1*d*p.y,d*p.x};
    return r;
}

Vec2 addVec(Vec2 p,Vec2 offs){
    Vec2 v;
    v.x =p.x+ offs.x;
    v.y =p.y+ offs.y;
    return v;
}

Vec2 mulv(Vec2 p,double u){
    Vec2 pr = {p.x*u,p.y*u};
    return pr;
}
    
void moveVec(Vec2 *v,Vec2 offs){ //brooom
    v->x += offs.x;
    v->y += offs.y;
}
        
Vec2 cenTri(Tri t){
    Vec2 v ={(t.p1->x+t.p2->x+t.p3->x)/3,(t.p1->y+t.p2->y+t.p3->y)/3};
    return v;
}

void updateTri(Tri *t,Vec2 v,double w){
    Vec2 cen = cenTri(*t);
    Vec2 r1 = {t->p1->x-cen.x,t->p1->y-cen.y};
    moveVec(t->p1,addVec(v,crossd(r1,w)));
    
    Vec2 r2 = {t->p2->x-cen.x,t->p2->y-cen.y};
    moveVec(t->p2,addVec(v,crossd(r2,w)));
    
    Vec2 r3 = {t->p3->x-cen.x,t->p3->y-cen.y};
    moveVec(t->p3,addVec(v,crossd(r3,w)));
}
    
int main(){
    int ms = 10;
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &win);
    time_t start, now, s_T, e_T;struct timespec delay;delay.tv_sec = 0;delay.tv_nsec = ms * 999999L;time(&start);
        
    initscr();
    clear();
    Vec2 p[3] = {{20,26},{22,45},{46,25}};Tri t = {&p[0],&p[1],&p[2]};
    
    
    double mass = 100;
    Vec2 v = {0,0};
    double w = 0.2;
    
    while(1){
        ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &win);
        Vec2 screen = {win.ws_col,win.ws_row};
    
        nanosleep(&delay,NULL);

        updateTri(&t,v,w);
        clear();
        scanln(t);
        refresh();
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Triangle at **t**

[image]

Triangle at **t+x**

[image]

Comment: Should your `struct triangle` / `Tri`  really keep pointers? It seems a bit risky since you rely on local instances to be alive at all times. Perhaps it's solid, but it looks a bit fishy to me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Most of the code is just copied from my other projects and I just wanted to make it work before optimizing.

Comment: If `crossd` is supposed to rotate a vector I would expect to see calls to `sin` and `cos` (unless it only rotates by some integer multiple of pi/2). E.g. `Vec2 crossd(Vec2.p, double d)` `{` `double s = sin(d);` `double c = cos(d);` `Vec2 r = { c*p.x - s*p.y, s*p.x + c*p.y };` `return r;` `}`.

Comment: `crossd` takes linear velocity and angular velocity of the triangle then calculates offset of all its three points which is tangential to r. @IanAbbott

Comment: @BrainlessCrab Do you mean `updateTri` takes the linear velocity and angular velocity?

Comment: Your triangle is not a rigid body. Define a rigid body with a center and rotation, and include the 3 vertices of the triangle _relative to the body frame_. This way you maintain the distances between the vertices under a rotation.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes I confused the functions also the function you provided makes the triangle explode.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou That will fix the problem but i still don't know what caused it.

Comment: @BrainlessCrab - I answered your question of _why_ then. See below.

Comment: @BrainlessCrab No, the `moveVec` call makes the triangle explode.

Comment: @IanAbbott - it is calling of `moveVec` within `updateTri` that causes the problem. The code to offset a vector _might_ correct or not. Using the code within the update instead of applying rotations is the problem.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Yes, that's what I meant. The calls to `moveVec` in the existing code make the triangle explode. It just explodes more quickly when `crossd` is changed to perform vector rotation. (I guess that was the intended purpose of `crossd` since it was passed a vector and an angle as parameters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
void updateTri(Tri *t,Vec2 v,double w){
    Vec2 cen = cenTri(*t);
    Vec2 r1 = {t->p1->x-cen.x,t->p1->y-cen.y};
    moveVec(t->p1,addVec(v,crossd(r1,w)));
    
    Vec2 r2 = {t->p2->x-cen.x,t->p2->y-cen.y};
    moveVec(t->p2,addVec(v,crossd(r2,w)));
    
    Vec2 r3 = {t->p3->x-cen.x,t->p3->y-cen.y};
    moveVec(t->p3,addVec(v,crossd(r3,w)));
}
```

which updates the verticles according to the instantaneous velocity of the vertex has over a finite amount of time (which is arbitrarily chosen as `timeStep = 1` here ).

**At any instant in time** the velocity of a vertex **r**<sub>i</sub> located relative to the rotation center is

**v**<sub>i</sub> = **ω** × **r**<sub>i</sub>

but at the next instant in time the position of the particle is

**r**<sub>i</sub><sup>*</sup> = **r**<sub>i</sub> + δt * **v**<sub>i</sub>

so the new velocity should be

**v**<sub>i</sub> = **ω** × **r**<sub>i</sub><sup>*</sup>

and so forth when δt → 0.

But for a finite time step, you cannot do the above, because it **is always going to move the points in a straight line** for each step δt. So you always going to have distortion.

What you need to do is consider the location of each vertex considering the overall rotation angle of the body

```
p1->x = cen->x + a*cos(θ) - b*sin(θ);
p1->y = cen->y + a*sin(θ) + b*cos(θ);
```

where `a` and `b` are constants describing the location of the vertex in the body frame (with zero rotation).

---

**Summary** Only rotations can preserve lengths, and so the kinematics of the problem (the quantities to describe all possible configurations and motions) need to include the orientation angle for each body, and the positions/velocties etc to be derived from this angle.

Answer (score 0):

These modifications to the code will preserve the size and shape of the triangle:

```
// return vector p rotated by angle d
Vec2 crossd(Vec2 p ,double d){
    double s = sin(d);
    double c = cos(d);
    Vec2 r = { c*p.x - s*p.y, s*p.x + c*p.y };
    return r;
}
```

```
void updateTri(Tri *t,Vec2 v,double w){
    Vec2 cen = cenTri(*t);
    v = addVec(v,cen);

    Vec2 r1 = {t->p1->x-cen.x,t->p1->y-cen.y};
    *t->p1 = addVec(v,crossd(r1,w));
    
    Vec2 r2 = {t->p2->x-cen.x,t->p2->y-cen.y};
    *t->p2 = addVec(v,crossd(r2,w));
    
    Vec2 r3 = {t->p3->x-cen.x,t->p3->y-cen.y};
    *t->p3 = addVec(v,crossd(r3,w));
}
```

Effectively, this is performing the following steps:

1. Get vector `cen` from origin to the center of the triangle.
2. Add vector `cen` to the delta displacement vector `v` for convenience (since this sum of vectors will be added to the rotated vectors `r1`, `r2`, `r3` later).
3. Set `r1`, `r2`, `r3` to the vertices `p1`, `p2`, `p3` minus `cen`, so that `r1`, `r2`, `r3` are the vertices relative to the center of the triangle.
4. Set `p1`, `p2`, `p3` to rotated versions of `r1`, `r2`, `r3` (rotated by the delta angle `d`) added to `v` (the original `v` plus `cen`).

In summary:

1. Translate triangle so rotation center is at the origin.
2. Rotate the radial vectors (from center to vertices) by delta angle.
3. Translate triangle back to original position.
4. Translate triangle by delta displacement.

Obviously, there is scope for optimization. All the vertices are being rotated by the same amount, so the sine and cosine can be calculated once (perhaps passed as parameters instead of the delta angle).